# GridLines in TimelinePlot do not export to EPS

Tags: plotting, export

The below `TimelinePlot` produces the proper figure within a *Mathematica* session, but when that figure is exported as an .eps figure (to be used in a $\LaTeX$ document) all portions appear *except* the vertical `GridLines`.  (They *do* appear if the figure is exported as a BMP format as shown below, but that format cannot be integrated into a $\LaTeX$ document under the $\LaTeX$ version I'm running.  I prefer .eps format for a number of other reasons as well.)

I'm using *Mathematica* version 10.1 under OS X on a Mac Pro.

```
timeLine = TimelinePlot[{
   {Labeled[Interval[{{2016, 1, 1}, {2016, 6, 15}}], "aaa"], 
    Labeled[Interval[{{2016, 2, 1}, {2016, 5, 15}}], "bbb"],
    Labeled[Interval[{{2017, 5, 5}, {2017, 8, 1}}], "ccc"]},
   {Labeled[Interval[{{2017, 4, 15}, {2018, 1, 1}}], "ddd"],
    Labeled[Interval[{{2018, 4, 15}, {2019, 1, 1}}], "eee"]}},
  PlotRange -> {{{2016, 1, 1}, {2018, 12, 15}}},
  GridLines -> {Automatic, None},
  GridLinesStyle -> {{Dashed, Green}, None},
  PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red},
  Spacings -> {1, 5},
  PlotLegends -> Placed[{"AAA", "BBB"}, Bottom],
  ImageSize -> 700]
```

How can I get the `GridLines` to export in the .eps format?

[image: my TimelinePlot]

Answer (score 4):

Figured it out.  For some unknown reason, `GridLines` created with `DateRange` and `Quantity` magically export in .eps.

```
 GridLines -> {DateRange["2016", "2019", Quantity[3, "Months"]], None}
```

I have no idea why this form works while `Automatic` does not.